# Drawing lines that overlap inside the perimeter using QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, line, print-composer, overlapping-features

I want to make a map, with two plots. I want to draw them only with a line along the perimeter of each one, with different colour. My problem is that when the lines overlap, only one colour is showed.

This is my problem:

[image: shapes]

Then I want to draw each on with different colour, I would like something like that (without the thin black line):

[image]

But I get this result:

[image]

Is there are any way to draw the lines inside the perimeter using QGIS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set your border to simple line and check *Only draw the line inside the polygone* (or  something like that) [image]

[image]

Comment: Which QGIS version is that ?

Comment: QGIS Version is 3.16.9

Answer (score 8):

One option is to set an offset that is 1/2 the stroke width.

[image]

You can adjust this offset if the thin white space between the polygons bother you. You can also change the `join style` to make the boundary more or less rounded.